# How to track the firebase login state changes in other component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hi I am trying to write a navbar component.

There are 2 places for a user to login inside the navbar. On the `navbar` component itself & another component called `settingMenu` which also handle the login. Setting menu is reusable component which used throughout the project so we added a login button there

The problem i am facing is When user logged in from the settingMenu. I want to update the navbar state.

Originally when no user is inside the app Navbar got the `LOGIN` button. What i want is when user us logged in via settingmenu I want to **RERENDERED** the navbar & change `LOGIN` button to `LOGOUT` button, But Its not happening.

Here is the navbar component

```
    <Button
      onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) =>
        setDisplayDialog(true)
      }
      className={classes.loginButton}
    >
      {firebase.auth().currentUser ? <p>Logout</p> : <p>Login</p>}
    </Button>
```

Since I am using the firebase google sign in method I am testing if user available with this syntax

```
firebase.auth().currentUser
```

Here is the setting menu component code

```
const signInWithGoogle = async (event: React.MouseEvent): Promise<void> => {
    const creds = await firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithPopup(AuthenticationProviders.google);
    await firebase.auth().updateCurrentUser(creds.user);
    hideDialogBox(event);
  };

<GoogleButton
            className={authStyle.GoogleButtonPlacement}
            onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent) => {
              signInWithGoogle(event);
            }}
          />
```

So how can i keep track of the state changes inside the settingmenu?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `currentUser` to track state changes, you're supposed to register an [auth state observer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data) as shown in the documentation:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // User is signed out.
  }
});
```

This gives you a callback that lets you respond to user sign-in state changes over time.  You would use this callback to call `setState()` to change whatever components need to update when the user signs in or out.

Comment: Can you make an example for the class component.
I am calling it every render inside the useEffect hook  and its working fine but,
component did update not working fore me